# How to test a component which is using a custom TypeScript React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm currently writing a React component in Typescript which makes use of a [axios-hooks](https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks) hook called useAxios. An example of this hook in use is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-wind-2vfq2):

```
 export const App = () => {
  const [{ data, loading, error }, refetch] = useAxios(
    "https://api.myjson.com/bins/820fc"
  );

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => refetch()}>refetch</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a test where I can mock the useAxios hook. I've tried creating a mock of the underlying axios component but I cant get this working:

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import { Test } from "../test"
import useAxios from "axios-hooks"

jest.mock("axios-hooks")
const mockedAxios = useAxios as jest.Mocked<typeof useAxios>

it("Displays loading", () => {
  // How to mock the return values in the following line?
  // mockedAxios.

  const { getByText } = render(<Test />)

  expect(getByText("Loading...")).toBeDefined()
})
```

I know that I shouldn't have to mock axios which is the underlying dependency, I should be able to mock useAxios, but I though I'd try anyhow.

I realise that this question has been mentioned many times on SO, but I can find a solution to this particular use case.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: so what happens if you `jest.mock("axios-hooks")` and later `useAxious.mockResolvedValue(dataToRespond)`? or do you need dynamic mocking based on URL?

Comment: As I'm using typescript it doesn't appear that I can do that. I assume that there's a way to do that using TS?

Comment: so issue is specific to type-check in TS, right? to me it looked like test runs but mock is not working on something like that

Comment: @skyboyer I've updated my question with an example test. I'm trying to figure out how to mock the hooks return values in TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this myself. To test the custom hook I did the following:

```
import * as useAxios from "axios-hooks"
jest.mock("axios-hooks")
const mockedAxios = useAxios as jest.Mocked<typeof useAxios>

it("Displays loading message", async () => {

  // Explicitly define what should be returned
  mockedAxios.default.mockImplementation(() => [
      {
        data: [],
        loading: true,
        error: undefined
      },
      () => undefined
    ])

  const { getByText } = render(<Test />)

  expect(getByText("Loading...")).toBeDefined()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mock the module and setup the expected result of `useAxios` per test e.g.

```
jest.mock('axios-hooks');

import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';

test('App displays loading when request is fetching', () => {
  useAxios.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({ loading: true }));
  // mount component
  // Verify "Loading" message is rendered
});
```

Comment: I'm using TypeScript and that answer doesn't appear to work

Comment: @BenSmith TS shouldn't really come into it, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It appears it does. Also see my updated question which has an incomplete test written in TS.

Comment: @BenSmith TS should be non-intrusive though (unless that's changed), so the above code should run. Looking at your example you've added `const mockedAxios = useAxios as jest.Mocked<typeof useAxios>` which takes us into TS territory, is that really necessary though? Have you tried the code as-is without any TS?

Answer (score 1):

I had to jump through some additional hoops to get the compiler happy with the `() => undefined` parameter. I'm not a fan of the double `as`, but I'm not sure how to make it less verbose as I'm new to TS.

```
import * as useAxios from 'axios-hooks';
import { AxiosPromise } from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import Test from 'components/Test';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('axios-hooks');
const mockedUseAxios = useAxios as jest.Mocked<typeof useAxios>;

it('renders a loading message', async () => {
  mockedUseAxios.default.mockImplementation(() => [
    {
      data: [],
      loading: true,
      error: undefined,
    },
    (): AxiosPromise => (undefined as unknown) as AxiosPromise<unknown>,
  ]);

  const { getByText } = render(<Test />);

  expect(getByText('Loading...')).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as mine bar the change in the returned function. Why didn't you just make a comment?

Comment: I considered this, but my answer also includes an additional import statement as well as the relevant imports missing from your example. I really appreciate you asking the question here and providing a good starting point for troubleshooting. Sometimes it's nice to have an answer with holistically sound approach in a single markup instance.

Comment: Ok fair point nicely made and Im glad I could help. I often refer to my own answer on mocking this library as it gets me every time!